# How to set bold text and/or highlight red in text editor using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to set bold text and/or highlight red in text editor using javascript ?

for example i select `PHP is a server-side scripting language` in text editor and press `bold button` How can i add taq `<b></b>` cover text `PHP is a server-side scripting language` by using javascript ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/99/

Comment: use tiny mce editor which will provide all this

Answer (score 0):

```
var element= document.getElementById("Paragraph/span tag that is required to be bold");
element.style.fontWeight="bold";
```

Use the above code in replacement of `<b>` tag.

Comment: but in text editor i can not fix id name, user can set every text to bold .

Comment: can you clearly tell me your requirements .What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: yes, select text and then press button, text that user select will bold. Like general text editor ^^

Comment: `code`function getSelectedParagraphText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
  }
  var parent = selection.anchorNode;
  while (parent != null && parent.localName != "P") {
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  if (parent == null) {
    return "";
  } else {
    return parent.innerText || parent.textContent;
  }
}`code`

Comment: the above will help you to get parent and then you can edit the property as i told you earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSelectedParagraphText() 
{ 
    if (window.getSelection) 
    {
        document.execCommand('bold'); 
    } 
    return window.getSelection();
}
```

use the above code